# shell_exec on windows server, how to debug?

Tags: python, php, shell-exec

I would like to run a Python script on a Windows Server (IIS) system with the PHP `shell_exec("python hubbeldibubbel.py parameter)`. If I start the Python script normally via the console, the script works, but not via web access.

What can be the cause? How can I debug this?
The Python script should only write something to a txt file at the moment.
The php-script:

```
<?php
$string = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$command = '"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Python.exe" C:\\inetpub\\vhosts\\...\\httpdocs\\nw.py ' . $string;


$output= shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

The python script:

```
import sys


string = sys.argv[1]

datei = open('datei.txt','a')
datei.write("aaa" + string)
print(string)
```

I tried other php commands.

Comment: python script does not output anything to stdout, what's the point in `echo $output;`?

Comment: this is either a typo or an error `\\...\\`

Comment: added print(string) to python script. There is no output. '\\...\' is justed to hide the path.

Comment: quick question what would happen if user requests `http://yourdomain/%26%26%20rmdir%20%2Fq%20%2Fs%20C%3A%5CUsers`, or in another words if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` equals `&& rmdir /q /s C:\Users`

Comment: add `echo file_exists('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Python.exe');` and `echo file_exists('C:\\inetpub\\vhosts\\...\\httpdocs\\nw.py');` just to make sure

Comment: that's confusing, file_exists says no, but i double checked it, python.exe is at this location.

Comment: file_exists says python.exe does not exist, maybe cause it's not in th allowed path?

Comment: Could it be that ISS service have no permission to access `python.exe` file or directory?

Answer (score 0):

You miss one slash here `AppData\Local`, should be `AppData\\Local`.

Comment: thanks for this hint, but this was not the problem